# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' and Cant resolve 'fs'

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, npm

ive just started to learn react and Ive been trying to get my react app to connect to my database with

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "*",
  password: "*",
  database: "media_app"
});
con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
});
```

but when i run the app with npm start it throws a bunch of errors

> Compiled with problems:X ERROR in ./node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js 1:13-30 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\xampp\htdocs\socialapp\node_modules\mysql\lib' BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
> This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
> - install 'crypto-browserify'
> If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
> resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }
> ERROR in ./node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Auth.js 3:13-30
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\xampp\htdocs\socialapp\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol' BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
> This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
> - install 'crypto-browserify'
> If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
> resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }
> ERROR in ./node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js 3:9-22
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\xampp\htdocs\socialapp\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences'

removing the `var mysql = require('mysql')` fixes it but then i cant connect to the database

There were 22 of these instead of 3 for other things it couldnt resolve like buffer, url, tls and other things but i just ran npm install ... for each one and the errors went away but these ones didnt when i ran npm install crypto or fs and i have tried to add

```
"browser": {
    "crypto": false
}
```

into package.json ive tried with the tsconig.json file
and ive tried adding resolve.fallback into the webpack config file but nothing seems to work

Comment: You can't run databases in the frontend. You're not running on NodeJS but on the browser, if you didn't know.

Answer (score 2):

First off, check all your import statements within your own files. I was using express on the backend and vscode intellisense auto-imported: `import { response } from 'express'` which caused an error with the 'fs' module.

You will also need to [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Polyfill) your code. As you can see in your error message, there is a breaking change as Webpack version 5 does not polyfill core node.js modules by default. For example, 'crypto' is a core node.js module that is no longer polyfilled by default.

This is how I resolved the polyfilling issue with npx-create-react-app and webpack5, hopefully it will work for you.

You will need to `npm i crypto-browserify` (as mentioned in your error message).

Then locate the webpack.config.js file at: yourapp/node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js

Look through the webpack.config.js file and find (you can ctrl + f and type 'resolve') the resolve block within the modules.exports block.
Here you need to provide a fallback for each module which cannot be found. This is the code that I used:

```
resolve: {
      fallback: {
        "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
       },
```

Restart your project after modifying the webpack.config.js file.

If you get subsequent errors which are stating that a polyfill is necessary, just repeat the above process for that specific module. For example, if I had an error message for 'stream', I would `npm i stream-browserify` and modify the webpack.config.js to:

```
resolve: {
      fallback: {
        "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
        "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
       },
```

Comment: OP please can you accept this answer? It would help me out. Thanks.